# Spatial data/Geography in SQL Server 2008, OR mappers and C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, spatial

I'm developing an application in C# that will use and store geographic locations using the data type "Geography" in SQL Server 2008. I was planning to use the Entity Framework but soon discovered it lacks support for spatial data. Does anyone have experience with or know of other OR mappers with spatial support?

The system will have few writes and many reads of geographical data. 
What is a good/preffered way to read/write spatial/Geography data from C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check out the following Stack Overflow post:

- [Spatial data types support in Linq2Sql or EF4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314523/spatial-data-types-support-in-linq2sql-or-ef4/1797509#1797509).

In addition, you might also be interested to give a look to [SketchPad](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SketchPad) from the MSDN Code Library, and its blog article [SketchPad: A Simple Drawing Editor](http://blogs.msdn.com/sbajaj/archive/2008/03/14/sketchpad-a-simple-drawing-editor2.aspx).

> SketchPad is a simple drawing editor
>   that allows you to create elementary
>   geometric shapes, and model them as entities
>   using either the Entity Framework or
>   LINQ to SQL. You can create, read, and
>   delete shapes, and use the built-in
>   spatial index to search for entities
>   by attribute value.