# Use geography and geometry datatypes in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2

I am developing a new GIS application with C# and Entity Framework 4. My database designed in SQL Server 2008 R2. I want to save map object position (latitude, longitude) in SQL Server `geography` datatype column and save path data in `geometry` datatype column.

How can use these column datatypes in Entity Framework?

Edit 1:
specific fields supported in `EF5`. But my application maybe run in XP and `EF5` not run in windows XP.

Comment: Geospatial types aren't supported in EF 4 - [they will be supported in EF 5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/05/04/spatial-types-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) (to be released with .NET 4.5)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spatial data/Geography in SQL Server 2008, OR mappers and C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967567/spatial-data-geography-in-sql-server-2008-or-mappers-and-c-sharp)

Comment: To read you can have a look at http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/yes-you-can-read-and-probably-write-spatial-data-with-entity-framework/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, with EF6, Spatial Data are supported on .net 4 ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/dn194325.aspx)). dot net framework 4 is the last version of .net which could be installed on Windows XP (Only SP3).